# How do I get the entire contents of a Wpf DataGrid with Coded UI Test

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, coded-ui-tests

We are automating a WPF application. The ui maps turn any `DataGrid` object we try to target into a `WpfControl` object.

We are able to explore the children and extract header and cell info from that object.  However only the visible Grid contents are available and that object doesn't have any properties like `ScrollIntoView` which would aid in consuming the contents that is currently OffScreen.

Surely there is a way to consume an entire `DataGrid`...???

Thanks In Advance,
Jeff

Comment: Some code would be useful

Answer (score 0):

The way I have done it before is to write a subscript which iterates over each cell using the keyboard, and then gets the data by copying the text to the clipboard and then retrieving it into the program.  I can usually get it to go through 5-10 cells per second, which is not incredibly fast, however it works.

I'll get to work tomorrow and I can grab you the code for it if that doesn't make sense.